# All functions are executing but I only called one in python

Tags: python, function, dictionary

The program is executing all the functions and I only want it to execute the one that is called in the function_call[operation] dictionary key.

```
   # Define functions for addition, subtraction, division, and multiplication
 # Write the equation and its output to a file 
    def add(num1, num2):
      answer =  num1 + num2
       with open("equation.txt", "w") as equation:
         return equation.write(f" {num1} + {num2} = {answer}")
    
     def subtract(num1, num2):
         answer =  num1 - num2
           with open("equation.txt", "w") as equation:
             return equation.write(f" {num1} - {num2} = {answer}")
    
     def multiply(num1, num2): 
        answer =  num1 * num2
          with open("equation.txt", "w") as equation:
            return equation.write(f" {num1} * {num2} = {answer}")
    
     def divide(num1, num2):
        answer =  num1/num2 
          with open("equation.txt", "w") as equation:
            return  equation.write(f" {num1} / {num2} = {answer}")
    
    # input first number
    # input operation
    # input second number 
       
      num1 = int(input("Please enter a valid first number: "))

      operation = input('''   Choose between:
       + : addition operation
       - : subtract operation
       * : multiply operation
       / : divide operation                
       :  ''') 

       num2 = int(input("Please enter a valid second number: "))

   # create dictionary with operation input as key and corresponding value as function
   # call diction value with operation variable as key to call the desired function or operation to be executed 
      function_call = {
         "+" : add(num1, num2),
         "-" : subtract(num1, num2),
         "*" : multiply(num1, num2),
         "/" : divide(num1, num2),
    
       }

       print(function_call[operation])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func = function_call[operation]
print(func(num1, num2))
```

Functions in Python are objects. So you could handle them as objects and interoperate between other objects. All you need is just provide arguments to run it (`call`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you define the `function_call` dictionary, you're calling all of the functions and storing the results of those calls in the dictionary:

```
      function_call = {
         "+" : add(num1, num2),
         "-" : subtract(num1, num2),
         "*" : multiply(num1, num2),
         "/" : divide(num1, num2),
       }
```

Instead, put the functions *themselves* in the dictionary *without calling them yet*:

```
      function_call = {
         "+" : add,
         "-" : subtract,
         "*" : multiply,
         "/" : divide,
       }
```

and then call the appropriate function *after* you fetch it from the dictionary:

```
print(function_call[operation](num1, num2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function_call = {
     "+" : add(num1, num2),
     "-" : subtract(num1, num2),
     "*" : multiply(num1, num2),
     "/" : divide(num1, num2),    
 }
```

Because there are parentheses after the function names, they are *called* during the definition of the dictionary.

If you don't want that, then don't put the parentheses:

```
function_call = {
     "+" : add,
     "-" : subtract,
     "*" : multiply,
     "/" : divide,
 }
```